# Why is this question "too localized"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, too-localized

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115560/drupal-views-rows-as-pure-data-model-or-mvc-alternative/) regarding theming Drupal views was quickly closed as "too localized" and I fail to understand why. **Views** is a de facto standard module for Drupal and the problem the OP was facing is regularly encountered by people not familiar with the module, including myself a couple of years ago.

Apparently this question was called for a close vote in the PHP chat room.

Comment: So would you say this is a programming question or a support question in how to use templating in Drupal? (I would tend a bit for the later, esp. in the way the OP asked).

Comment: @hakre Drupal questions are often a bit murky like that. I would lean towards your assessment too, but technically the solution does involve code (and could have involved more had a different type of answer been given - the potential is definitely there). I have to say it's not a very good question though, probably could have been closed for at least one other different reason. Too localised doesn't seem right here

Comment: While it might not have been _correct_, if one honestly assumed that the question would be likely to only help the OP (and I can see how people would have that assumption the way it was initially asked), then it would seem quite a bit more appropriate. As Clive said, Drupal can be murky waters.

Comment: @TimPost It was posted in the PHP chat as only "[cv-pls] link" without a single line about what is wrong with the question. I'm not surprised that such a practice leads to bad closures.

Comment: And the question is a duplicate, as I suspected, which is pretty much the opposite of too localized.

Comment: @MadScientist They do have a user script that one boxes such links, but I'll have a chat with them about it.

Comment: From the revision summary, it looks like it had something to do with semantics pedantry.